# What are the color and transparency of the OS X menubar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I want to have an application I'm writing mirror the color and transparency set for the OS X menubar, but there doesn't seem to be any way to find the exact values besides trial and error.

Does anyone have a complete listing, for all four possible combinations of enabled/disabled dark mode and transparency?

Edit: I'm trying to find the rgba values of the menu bar background color for each of the four possible combinations

Comment: It's more if an effect depends on what's in the background. What are you gonna use it for? Possible answer http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20711/how-to-re-create-this-ios7-blur-effect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/Applications/Utilities/Digital\ Color\ Meter.app` to get the RGB value of any pixel shown on your monitor.

[image]

Comment: That does not help me find the color of the menu bar background because of its transparency.

Comment: Don't the RGB values in transparency mode depend on the desktop background/picture you are using?

Comment: Yes, but I want my application to work regardless of the desktop background picture set.

Comment: How can you know this beforehand then?

Comment: It's why I'm asking for the ARGB value of the menubar background (depending on transparency/dark mode settings) - so I can have my application result in the same color when over the same desktop background picture.